# Error while connecting phone with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to connect my phone with android studio

---

1. Download google USB driver

---

2. My device is shown in the portable device not in other device folders why? [screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44vVG.png)

Comment: AppData is a hidden folder. In order to see it you must first enable hidden folders in File Explorer. Is debug mode enabled on your device?

Comment: Thanks, Now SDK folder is showing.

Comment: Did you manage to connect your device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to connect an Android device to Android Studio for debugging purposes, you first have to enabled USB Debugging from the Settings->Developer Options menu. By default this menu is hidden. To unlock it, you have to go into Settings->About and tap Build for 7 times.

Google USB drivers are not mandatory but you should install the drivers of your specific device provided by the manufacturer. A list of useful links for drivers can be consulted [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers).

Further documentation on how to use a physical device with Android Studio can be found [this Android Developer page](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).